# How can I "tell" MySQL to return me an associated value with multiple aggregate functions in a single query grouped by a category?

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

[I have these two tables:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urTBB.png) my database is bigger but the query only involves these two, they are related by the Primary Key "Id_TipoMed" and the Foreign Key "TipoMedicamento_FK"

I'm trying to do a query that shows me the total earnings per category(this by multiplying quantity("cantidad") and price("precio")), in this case Type of medicine ("Tipo Medicamento") is said category, also I want to show the one for each category that has the maximum earnings and then show the percentage that it represents of the total per category, I did this code:

```
SELECT 
    T.Id_TipoMed, 
    M.Nombre, 
    MAX(Cantidad*Precio) Ganancia_Medicamento, 
    SUM(Cantidad*Precio)Ganancia_Neta, 
    CONCAT(MAX(Cantidad*Precio)*100/SUM(Cantidad*Precio),'%') Porcentaje_Respecto_Tipo
FROM Medicamento M 
    INNER JOIN TipoMedicamento T ON M.TipoMedicamento_FK=T.Id_TipoMed
GROUP BY TipoMedicamento_FK
HAVING 
    SUM(Cantidad*Precio) = (
        SELECT 
            SUM(Cantidad*Precio) 
        FROM Medicamento M2 
        WHERE M2.TipoMedicamento_FK=T.Id_TipoMed)
    AND 
    MAX(Cantidad*Precio) = (
        SELECT 
            MAX(Cantidad*Precio) 
        FROM Medicamento M2
        WHERE M2.TipoMedicamento_FK=T.Id_TipoMed);
```

My only problem with the query is that it shows me the incorrect name, it does not correspond with the name that has associated the maximum earnings, what am I doing wrong?, because by doing the subquery that way worked in the past when doing less complicated queries that did not involved multiple aggregate functions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-aggregate expressions in the SELECT list of a GROUP BY query (which do not also appear in the GROUP BY clause) are indeterminate. There is no guarantee that the value returned for the non-aggregate will be a value associated with the rows value returned by an aggregate function such as MAX().

Databases other than MySQL would return an error with the expression `M.Nombre` in the SELECT list, because that expression does not also appear in the `GROUP BY`.

MySQL doesn't return an error for the statement because of a MySQL-specific extension to GROUP BY behavior.  This is documented behavior, explained in the MySQL Reference Manual.  (This non-standard behavior is a "gotcha" for SQL authors that aren't familiar with this MySQL quirk.)

(It is possible to get MySQL to better conform to the SQL standard, and return an error message for this query, by including ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in sql_mode.)

---

It's not clear why the statement includes a join to `Tipo_Medicamento` table. It appears unnecessary.

Given that `id_tipomed` is the primary key of the table, there will be at most one row with a specific value, so the join isn't duplicating any rows. And we can figure out that the unqualified references to `cantidad` and `precio` are references to columns in the `Medicamento` table.  (If those had been qualified, the reader wouldn't have been forced to look at the table definitions to figure out which table those were in.)

We do know that the equality comparison in the join predicate will exclude any rows that have a NULL value in the `tipomedicamento_fk` column. But we could do that more efficiently without a join operation.

What we can't tell (from the information provided) is if the database is enforcing a foreign key constraint, i.e. whether we are expecting values in  `tipomedicamento_fk` that don't refer to a row in the table.  If there are, then the join operation would exclude them.

Aside from that, there doesn't appear to be any reason for join operation.

And the HAVING clause seems way more complicated than it needs to be to exclude rows that have NULL values returned by the MAX() and SUM() aggregates. If the value returned for the `MAX(foo)` aggregate is non-null, we know that the value for `SUM(foo)` is guaranteed to be non-null.

The return from this query is equivalent to the return from the original:

```
SELECT m.tipomedicamento_fk
     , m.nombre
     , MAX(m.cantidad*m.precio)  AS `Ganancia_Medicamento`
     , SUM(m.cantidad*m.precio)  AS `Ganancia_Neta`
     , CONCAT(MAX(m.cantidad*m.precio)*100/SUM(m.cantidad*m.precio),'%')
         AS `Porcentaje_Respecto_Tipo`
  FROM Medicamento m
 WHERE m.tipomedicamento_fk IS NOT NULL
 GROUP
    BY m.tipomedicamento_fk
HAVING `Ganancia_Medicamento` IS NOT NULL
```

---

The value returned for the `m.nombre` expression is indeterminate. We are guarnateed that it will be a value from a row in the group, but it's not guaranteed to be any particular row.

If we want to return the value from the row that has the largest value of the `m.cantidad*m.precio` expression, we need to write the SQL differently.

There's a couple of patterns we can use.

Since we're returning a single column, we could use a correlated subquery in the SELECT list. We can use an ORDER BY to get the highest value of "cantidad*precio" first, and specify LIMIT 1 so we only get one row returned.

```
SELECT m.tipomedicamento_fk
     , ( SELECT o.nombre
           FROM Medicamento o
          WHERE o.tipomedicamento_fk = m.tipomedicamento_fk
          ORDER
             BY (o.cantidad*o.precio) DESC
              , o.nombre DESC
          LIMIT 1
       )  AS `nombre`
     , MAX(m.cantidad*m.precio)  AS `Ganancia_Medicamento`
     , SUM(m.cantidad*m.precio)  AS `Ganancia_Neta`
     , CONCAT(MAX(m.cantidad*m.precio)*100/SUM(m.cantidad*m.precio),'%')
         AS `Porcentaje_Respecto_Tipo`
  FROM Medicamento m
 WHERE m.tipomedicamento_fk IS NOT NULL
 GROUP
    BY m.tipomedicamento_fk
HAVING `Ganancia_Medicamento` IS NOT NULL
```

This isn't the only way to do it. There are other query patterns that would return an equivalent result.

Comment: Thank you for such a complete answer! ^^

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance that there are multiple Medicamento rows with the same TipoMedicamento_FK? If so, then grouping by TipoMedicamento_FK will not necessarily produce accurate values for columns that are not part of the group by statement. To check this, try running a query to count the number of times each TipoMedicamento_FK value occurs, and make sure that there are not duplicates.

If there are duplicated TipoMedicamento_FK values, then you need to add another column to the group by statement. For example, you might group by Nombre AND TipoMedicamento_FK.

Comment: I wasn't considering that, and yes multiple rows reference the same TipoMedicamento_FK, thanks!